# How far can we trust calculus with infinity?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, nan, infinity

In this simple calculus, all the results are OK :

```
program main

    real :: x,y,z
    
    x=0.0
    y=1/x; print *,y
    y=log(x); print *,y
    z=0.99; y=z**(1/x); print *,y
    z=1.0; y=z**(1/x); print *,y
    z=1.01; y=z**(1/x); print *,y
    
end program main
```

I found it very convenient. Indeed, if X is an array, I have not to do loop check (e.g. `x(i)/=0`) on array elements to calculate `z**(1/x(i))`. But I wonder how far can we trust this kind of calculus ?

Comment: Your code may not be standard conforming Fortran.  Fortran 2018, 16.9.1:  _ A program shall not invoke an intrinsic procedure under circumstances where a value to be assigned to a subroutine argument or returned as a function result is not representable by objects of the specified type and type parameters._   Fortran 2018, 10.5.1.2.4: _The execution of any numeric operation whose result is not defined by the arithmetic used by the processor is
prohibited._   If your Fortran processor considers infinity to be non-representable, you have a problem.

Comment: Do not prepend some `fortran:` or similar to question titles. We have tasks for this. If you need Fortran to be mentioned, mention it in the title itself. You may have to require strict conformance to IEEE754 standards to be sure what will happen with your code. However, be worried about compile-time arithmetics, that is tricky.

Comment: Also you are aware of the `where` construct? But basically I would strongly advise not doing the above.

Comment: AFAIK the behavior of such code is processor-dependant